# Exceptions constantly thrown when launching app with my custom WINAPI Debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I'm in the process of experimenting with creating my own custom debugger with C++ in Visual Studio 2017. Testing a few console applications it is fine. However when I launch notepad with it, it is OK until I hit File -> Open dialog and it goes into constant loop with output these two exceptions code and the open dialog box doesn't open:

```
Exception: 3221356611
Exception: 998
```

When same process was launched under WinDbg these exceptions didn't occur. 
The code is compiled as x86 and launching 32-bit process on Windows 10 1803 build 17134.523 x64.

Any suggestions on what might cause these?

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map < LPVOID, std::wstring > DllNameMap;

int main()
{
    std::wstring filename(L"c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe");
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent;

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        (LPWSTR)filename.c_str(),           // Command line
        NULL,               // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,               // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,              // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,   // No creation flags
        NULL,               // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,               // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,                // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)                // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (DebugActiveProcess(pi.dwProcessId))
    {
        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);

        std::cout << "Debugger attached!" << std::endl;
        EnterDebugLoop(&debugEvent,pi.hProcess);
    }
    return 0;
}

void EnterDebugLoop(const LPDEBUG_EVENT DebugEv,HANDLE hProcess)
{

    DWORD dwContinueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE; // exception continuation 

    for (;;)
    {
        // Wait for a debugging event to occur. The second parameter indicates
        // that the function does not return until a debugging event occurs. 

        WaitForDebugEvent(DebugEv, INFINITE);

        // Process the debugging event code. 

        switch (DebugEv->dwDebugEventCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Process the exception code. When handling 
            // exceptions, remember to set the continuation 
            // status parameter (dwContinueStatus). This value 
            // is used by the ContinueDebugEvent function. 

            std::cout << "Exception: " << DebugEv->u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode << std::endl;

            switch (DebugEv->u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
            {
            case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
                std::cout << "ACCESS VIOLATION" << std::endl;
                // First chance: Pass this on to the system. 
                // Last chance: Display an appropriate error. 
                break;

            case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:

                std::cout << "BREAKPOINT" << std::endl;
                // First chance: Display the current 
                // instruction and register values. 
                break;

            case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT:
                std::cout << "DATATYPE MISALIGNMENT" << std::endl;
                // First chance: Pass this on to the system. 
                // Last chance: Display an appropriate error. 
                break;

            case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
                std::cout << "SINGLE STEP" << std::endl;
                // First chance: Update the display of the 
                // current instruction and register values. 
                break;

            case DBG_CONTROL_C:
                std::cout << "CTRL+C" << std::endl;
                // First chance: Pass this on to the system. 
                // Last chance: Display an appropriate error. 
                break;

            default:
                    // Handle other exceptions. 
                break;
            }

            break;

        case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            std::cout << "Create Thread" << std::endl;
            // As needed, examine or change the thread's registers 
            // with the GetThreadContext and SetThreadContext functions; 
            // and suspend and resume thread execution with the 
            // SuspendThread and ResumeThread functions. 
            break;

        case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            std::cout << "Create Process" << std::endl;
            // As needed, examine or change the registers of the
            // process's initial thread with the GetThreadContext and
            // SetThreadContext functions; read from and write to the
            // process's virtual memory with the ReadProcessMemory and
            // WriteProcessMemory functions; and suspend and resume
            // thread execution with the SuspendThread and ResumeThread
            // functions. Be sure to close the handle to the process image
            // file with CloseHandle.

            //dwContinueStatus = OnCreateProcessDebugEvent(DebugEv);
            break;

        case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Display the thread's exit code. 
            std::cout << "Exit Thread Exit Code " << DebugEv->u.ExitThread.dwExitCode << std::endl;


            //dwContinueStatus = OnExitThreadDebugEvent(DebugEv);
            break;

        case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            // Display the process's exit code. 
            std::cout << "Exit process Exit Code " << DebugEv->u.ExitProcess.dwExitCode << std::endl;
            ///dwContinueStatus = OnExitProcessDebugEvent(DebugEv);
            break;

        case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
        {
            PVOID pDllPath = NULL;
            PUCHAR DllPath[(MAX_PATH + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)];
            DWORD dwLen = 0;
            ZeroMemory(DllPath, sizeof(DllPath));

            if (DebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpImageName == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }

            // read DLL name pointer value
            if (ReadProcessMemory(
                hProcess,
                DebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpImageName,
                &pDllPath, sizeof(PVOID),
                &dwLen) && pDllPath)
            {
                dwLen = (DebugEv->u.LoadDll.fUnicode ? MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR) : MAX_PATH);

                // read DLL name
                if (ReadProcessMemory(
                    hProcess,
                    pDllPath,
                    DllPath, dwLen,
                    &dwLen))
                {
                    char szDllPath[MAX_PATH], *lpszDllName = NULL;

                    if (DebugEv->u.LoadDll.fUnicode)
                    {
                        std::wstring path((wchar_t*)DllPath);
                        DllNameMap.insert(std::make_pair(DebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpBaseOfDll, path));
                        std::wcout << "Image loaded (Unicode): " << path.c_str() << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // todo: Add to DllNameMAp
                        std::wcout << "Image loaded: " << DllPath << std::endl;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Error processing memory : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::wcout << "ERROR reading process memory : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
        }
            // Read the debugging information included in the newly 
            // loaded DLL. Be sure to close the handle to the loaded DLL 
            // with CloseHandle.

            ///dwContinueStatus = OnLoadDllDebugEvent(DebugEv);
            break;

        case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            std::wcout << "Unload DLL: " << DllNameMap[DebugEv->u.UnloadDll.lpBaseOfDll] << std::endl;
            break;

        case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT:
            // Display the output debugging string. 
            std::wcout << "Debug Event" << std::endl;
            if (DebugEv->u.DebugString.fUnicode)
            {
                std::wcout << (wchar_t)DebugEv->u.DebugString.lpDebugStringData << std::endl;
            }

            //dwContinueStatus = OnOutputDebugStringEvent(DebugEv);
            break;

        case RIP_EVENT:
            //dwContinueStatus = OnRipEvent(DebugEv);
            break;
        }

        // Resume executing the thread that reported the debugging event. 

        ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEv->dwProcessId,
            DebugEv->dwThreadId,
            dwContinueStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExceptionCode` 3221356611 (0xC0020043) is `STATUS_UNWIND`. You should be able to check for the `EXCEPTION_UNWINDING` and `EXCEPTION_EXIT_UNWIND` flags in the `ExceptionRecord.ExceptionFlags` field.  See the section on Stack Unwinding in ["A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling"](http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_crash_course_depths_of_win32_seh.htm).

Comment: not related to problem, but you for example not close handles on `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT`, on `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - sorry but 3221356611 (0xC0020043) is `RPC_NT_INTERNAL_ERROR`. unrelated to `STATUS_UNWIND` (`C0000027`)

Comment: and your fatal error - `dwContinueStatus` on `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT` in most case (if this is not your breakpoint/single step ) must be set to `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` if this is first chanche. is last chanche - terminate process or ask user - to where change execution context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `3221356611` this is `0xC0020043` - `RPC_NT_INTERNAL_ERROR`
- `998` this is `0x3e6` - `ERROR_NOACCESS` (*Invalid access to memory
  location*)

your main error that you unconditionally return `DBG_CONTINUE` always. but on `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT` you mast return this code only if you handle exception. otherwise (and if `dwFirstChance == TRUE` so this is first chance exception) you must return `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`. if you return `DBG_CONTINUE` - the program begin continue execute from current context. if you return `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` - the `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` will be called in target process, which call `RtlDispatchException` and where will be called exception handlers. read more - [Structured Exception Handling](http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_crash_course_depths_of_win32_seh.htm)

but because you never return `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` - program exception handlers never called. by your 2 exceptions codes even easy locate place, where this happens:
[image]

the `RpcpRaiseException` is called, which internal call `RaiseException(ERROR_NOACCESS..)` so you view 998 exception. if you return `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` here - application byself handle this exception and never return from `RaiseException` call. context will be swithched to `__except{}` block. but because you return `DBG_CONTINUE` - the `RaiseException` return  control and `RpcReportFatalError` called, which internal  call `RaiseException(RPC_NT_INTERNAL_ERROR..)` so you and view `3221356611 (0xC0020043)`

your next error that you not close `hFile` on `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` - *When the debugger is finished with this file, it should close the handle using the CloseHandle function.* the same error on `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`

also your error in how you begin debug process - you must not use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, must not use `DebugActiveProcess` and `ResumeThread`. you need only set `DEBUG_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` and all. not need create process in suspended state and main not call `DebugActiveProcess` here. this api call is bad designed, it create additional thread in target process. for say xp at this stage this at all was fatal.